# Tesseract confuses 7 for 1, returns nothing for text.

Tags: numbers, field, ocr, tesseract, digits

I am attempting to OCR scanned forms, with fields of numbers and some text. However, running tesseract on the cropped text does not yield the correct results.

For example, for the number 7: [image: Number 7]

The result given is 1, when running:

```
tesseract -psm 10 7test.jpg out digits
```

Despite the stroke through the seven.

Meanwhile, for the text fields it has even more difficulty, yielding nothing for the following field:

[image: test name]

Is there any easy way to improve the accuracy here? Ideally avoiding producing a great training set due to the hand-written nature of the forms.

On the name field I can probably improve the orientation and remove the lines enclosing the field, but the lack of any output is worrying.

For the digits, I have no idea, except perhaps producing a manual training set from the forms.